# Paypal chained adaptive payment in android application

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I'm trying to build an application with paypal adaptive payment (chained) but I dont know from where to start. I have built a demo that uses Paypal_MPL library app but have not tested it since I belong to a country which is not supported. However I'll apply for live credentials for testing. I need help in integrating adaptive payment in my application using Paypal_MPL library. Please Advise.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The current Android and iOS SDK's use the REST API calls and they do not yet support chained or parallel payments. Both the SDK's and the REST calls are new and extra features are being added to them. Hopefully support for all Adaptive Payment calls will be added. 
The old payment libraries weren't created with built in support for Adaptive Payment calls either - sorry.

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick Sir, I have used paypal_mpl library and set up adaptive payment using advancedPayment. But the problem is that I can test my app in sandbox as Paypal library fails to initialize in sandbox environment. It might be cause I'm from a country which is not supported in paypal countries list. Can you please help !!

Comment: @Shah, maybe you could register another account (in a "good" country) for testing?

Comment: @naxa Thanks for the comment but I have implemented the paypal mechanism and tested it and now the system is working on live payments.